# get text from keyboard advanced framework to browser

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, blueprint

i made this example in my game ,the browser is from lambda browser and the keyborad is from Advanced framework VR 5.0 , i want  when write with the keyboard , the input of the browser ( google ) display the text , any one can help me on it, with blueprints[image: un]